# Sequlize update propeties by condition

Tags: sequelize.js

Is that possible to update db some propertyies at onc call with multiple condtions?

```
const MyModel = sequlize.define('myModel',{
id:DataTypes.number,
condA:DataTypes.boolean,
condB:DataTypes.boolean,
foo:DataTypes.string,
boo:DataTypes.string
})
```

i want to update foo if condition a is true
and update boo if condition b is true.
currently, i connect to db twice and its seems less efficent. im sure it is possible to update at one call

```
await myModel.update({foo:'foo'},{where:{condA : true})
await myModel.update({boo:'boo'},{where:{condB % 2 : true})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is a DBMS that supports such syntax the SQL standard and Sequelize that follows it both don't support updating different sets of fields on different conditions in one SQL query.